# Plotting plain data (single value lists) in 3D

Tags: plotting

**Some Chemistry data sets**

I am trying to plot some titration data with Mathematica. I have done 4 experiments and gathered around 70 pH points (one for each milliliter) during each session, and therefore I have 4 sets of pH measurements. Now, in each experiment I used a different concentration of an extra compound (something that affects the titration), so the curves should, when plotted in 3D, show a nice behavior, since the precipitant forces the protons out of the acid (the Chemistry part here; may ignore).

---

Now, this curves are not meant to be plotted with equals distances, as in the image and what I've managed to do.

[image: H3PO4 titration with KOH and CaCl2]

The standard why of plotting these 4 curves is by placing them at the $\log_{10}$ of the concentration of the extra compound ($\text{CaCl}_2$ for those who might be interested). My data looks like this:

```
L1 = {1.63, 1.67, 1.71, 1.76, 1.80, 1.85, 1.90, 1.94, 1.99, 2.03, 
  2.08, 2.11, 2.16, 2.21, 2.27, 2.35, 2.43, 2.52, 2.62, 2.72, 2.86, 
  3.05, 3.34, 4.06, 4.93, 5.28, 4.25, 4.26, 4.30, 4.37, 4.41, 4.48, 
  4.55, 4.60, 4.67, 4.78, 4.85, 4.94, 5.05, 5.19, 5.34, 5.49, 5.70, 
  5.99, 6.32, 6.76, 7.52, 8.49, 9.56, 10.61, 10.90, 11.09, 11.23, 
  11.33, 11.41, 11.48, 11.54, 11.59, 11.64, 11.68, 11.71, 11.73, 
  11.77, 11.80, 11.83, 11.85, 11.88, 11.89, 11.90, 11.91, 11.93}

L2 = {1.36, 1.44, 1.49, 1.55, 1.62, 1.68, 1.74, 1.82, 1.89, 1.98, 
  2.04, 2.09, 2.16, 2.26, 2.35, 2.47, 2.63, 2.83, 3.18, 4.23, 4.68, 
  4.89, 3.95, 4.12, 4.07, 4.07, 4.11, 4.15, 4.21, 4.27, 4.34, 4.42, 
  4.50, 4.59, 4.68, 4.81, 4.93, 5.11, 5.37, 5.78, 7.28, 10.28, 10.92, 
  11.17, 11.35, 11.45, 11.54, 11.62, 11.67, 11.72, 11.77, 11.81, 
  11.84, 11.91, 11.93, 11.95, 11.97, 11.98, 12.00, 12.02, 12.04, 
  12.05, 12.06, 12.08, 12.09, 12.10, 12.11, 12.12, 12.14, 12.14, 
  12.15, 12.16}

L3 = {1.48, 1.57, 1.62, 1.66, 1.72, 1.75, 1.81, 1.87, 1.92, 2.06, 
  2.10, 2.16, 2.21, 2.28, 2.35, 2.43, 2.51, 2.62, 2.75, 2.95, 3.19, 
  3.64, 4.10, 4.61, 4.84, 4.16, 4.11, 4.11, 4.00, 4.07, 4.12, 4.16, 
  4.19, 4.24, 4.32, 4.35, 4.40, 4.46, 4.53, 4.63, 4.70, 4.79, 4.92, 
  5.07, 5.23, 5.55, 6.23, 7.50, 7.87, 9.68, 10.49, 10.81, 11.01, 
  11.13, 11.24, 11.31, 11.37, 11.41, 11.46, 11.49, 11.50, 11.54, 
  11.57, 11.60, 11.62, 11.64, 11.67, 11.68, 11.70, 11.71, 11.72, 
  11.73, 11.74, 11.75, 11.5, 11.77, 11.78, 11.80, 11.81, 11.80, 11.82,
   11.83}

L4 = {1.79, 1.84, 1.98, 2.01, 2.04, 2.08, 2.12, 2.16, 2.20, 2.24, 
  2.30, 2.34, 2.39, 2.43, 2.50, 2.58, 2.66, 2.76, 2.89, 3.02, 3.24, 
  3.72, 4.95, 5.47, 5.68, 4.77, 4.74, 4.82, 4.89, 5.00, 5.15, 5.33, 
  5.58, 5.89, 6.22, 6.46, 6.64, 6.80, 6.97, 7.11, 7.30, 7.52, 7.82, 
  8.55, 10.10, 10.70, 10.97, 11.13, 11.21, 11.33, 11.40, 11.46, 11.52,
   11.58, 11.62, 11.66, 11.70, 11.70, 11.75, 11.77, 11.80, 11.83, 
  11.85, 11.87, 11.89, 11.91, 11.92, 11.94, 11.95, 11.97, 11.98}

L5 = {2.07, 2.09, 2.12, 2.17, 2.23, 2.26, 2.28, 2.31, 2.41, 2.45, 
   2.48, 2.52, 2.58, 2.63, 2.69, 2.76, 2.85, 2.95, 3.14, 3.28, 3.48, 
   3.82, 5.11, 5.76, 6.06, 6.23, 5.72, 5.83, 6.05, 6.28, 6.47, 6.50, 
   6.70, 6.82, 6.96, 7.08, 7.18, 7.22, 7.35, 7.47, 7.60, 7.74, 7.91, 
   8.15, 8.51, 9.54, 10.17, 10.63, 10.98, 11.22, 11.37, 11.49, 11.59, 
   11.68, 11.74, 11.79, 11.84, 11.90, 11.92, 11.95, 12.02, 12.07, 
   12.11, 12.15, 12.18, 12.20, 12.22, 12.24, 12.25, 12.28, 12.31, 
   12.34, 12.36}
```

So, each value there is the y-value, the number of item is the x-value and the z-value (or whatever it must be) is, for each complete set, the logarithm of the concentration.

Any help is appreciated!

---

Example (extract from `L1`):

```
L = {{1.63,0,-0.7}, {1.67,1,-0.7}, {1.71,2,-0.7}, {1.76,3,-0.7}, {1.80,4,-0.7}, {1.85,5,-0.7}}
```

---

The coordinates:

```
{{L3, L1, L2, L4, L5}, {Log10[0.199], Log10[0.099], Log10[0.15], 
  Log10[0.054], Log10[0.0265]}}
```

Comment: Sorry to say I don't understand this question.  Could you possibly give a much smaller example of the input and output that you want?  I assume a set of X,Y,Z coordinates to be plotted?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hang on…

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is the example okay?

Comment: The first two values seem clear now but I don't know how to calculate `-0.7`.  Assume I know *nothing* about your field or process (which is probably close to correct).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The -0.7 is a constant that depends on the experiment. It can't be easily calculated, if not at all, from the data. i.e. it is given.

Comment: I wish you had said that sooner; I was feeling pretty stupid. :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not yet an answer, but rather an exploration of the question.  Please tell me if this is somewhat like what you need except without a surface joining the points in the *y* direction (horizontally in the orientation below):

```
f[L_List, z_] := MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]], z} &, L]

points = Join @@ MapThread[f, {{L1, L2, L3, L4}, {-0.7, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0}}];

ListPointPlot3D[points, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

---

@Fiire I see that you Accepted this answer.  Thanks, but as it's not complete I suggest you wait.  Also, you might receive a better answer from someone else.  Because the points don't quite align a naive joining results in something I don't think you want:

```
lines = MapThread[f, {{L1, L2, L3, L4}, {-0.7, -0.4, -0.2, 0.0}}] ~Flatten~ {2};

Graphics3D[Line @ lines, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Could you provide additional guidelines for how the data is to be handled?  Should an attempt to align the samples be made?

Comment: Exactly that! That's what I need.

Comment: @Fiire Okay, I'll implement that soon; right now I'm taking a break.

Comment: It's almost how I need it. The order is supposed to be L3,L1,L4,L2. I don't know if that would be possible to add a surface, which would make the graph a little bit more readable, as for interpretation.

Comment: @Fiire Okay, that helps.  I'm still having trouble making a surface, primarily I think because the data sets are not all the same length.  Is it acceptable to discard the trailing points in the longer lists?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think they are crucial here.

Comment: I don't mean to bother. Sorry if I do. Have you had any luck with the surface? I also added another list of data just to add to the emotion.

Comment: @Fiire Sorry, I forgot about this.  I can't work on it now but I'll see if I can draw some attention to this question.